# resize all contents of window?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm making a game with Tkinter canvas, and I'm planning to expand it (for UI) using grid.
Problem I'm facing is, that as it is, game window takes up bit more than the height of my screen. If I add anything on top, some parts will be completely off-screen. I can not change resolution of the canvas, as some parts move on pixel-basis. Thus I want to change size of the whole 'image' that Tkinter renders(canvas + other possible labels), that is the whole window.
Is there a way to do so?

[window snapshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYQNZ.png)

Comment: for games I would rather use [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news), [PyGame-Zero](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), [Arcade](https://arcade.academy/) or eventually [PyGlet](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). OR eventually [GodotEngine](https://godotengine.org/) which uses language similar to Python.

Comment: `canvas` doesn't render it as image but keeps every element separatelly and you would have to resize elements before putting on `canvas` - and it means you have to use variables to move objects - or recalculate all position directly before putting on canvas. Eventaully you can use `pillow` to render all on one image, resize it and later put this image on canvas.

Comment: is it possible to move images by a fraction of pixel? If so, then Iˊd have to recalculate the size and position of all objects and change it. Looks troublesome.  How can I render the image using pillow? As I cannot find it anywhere else.

Comment: you can't move by a fraction of pixel - but nobody would even see so small move. You can keep position as float and it will be cumulate fractions of pixel but you move it by value converted to integer. In one move this franction can be reduced to zero but in other move cumulation of fractions will give value bigger then 1 and then it will move.  Game is only illusion and it doesn't have to be perfect - peopel will not see small differences.

Comment: `pillow` has object `Image` which has function `paste` to put one image on another. You can create one big image - like original window size -  and use `paste` to put all elements on this image, and later you can `resize()` it and display on canvas. This method uses `PyGame` - it create "surface" in memory, you draw all element on this surface in memory and finally it put this surface in window and you get new surface to draw next moves. It is called "double buffering" and it reduce flickering but it also gives you surface with all elements which you can resize before display.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement it, will update if Iˊll have some question.